# Transformation matrix between two line segments

Tags: math, matrix

Having two line segments (in the same 2D plane) defined by four endpoints `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` how to calculate transformation matrix which will transform first line segment into second?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131696/369162) answer to be almost what I need - I just cant translate it into code.

Comment: It would be a different answer depending on whether the line segments are in the same 2D plane or 3D space.  If it's the former, it's a simple translation and rotation.  If it's the latter, it's a translation and three successive rotations.  Those matricies are easily expressed in terms of rotation angles.

Comment: Line segments are in the same 2D plane, and scaling is also relevant.

Comment: The rotational transformation is unitary, no scaling issue.  Use the cross product to calculate the sine of the rotational angle and use it in the rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @duffymo Can you help with the implementation?

Comment: Can?  Yes.  Will I?  No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find lengths of segments `len_ab, len_cd`

translation matrix by `(-a.x, -a.y)`

rotation matrix by angle

```
 atan2((d.x-c.x)*(b.y-a.y)-(d.y-c.y)*(b.x-a.x), 
       (d.x-c.x)*(b.x-a.x)+(d.y-c.y)*(b.y-a.y)
```

scaling by both axes with coefficient `len_cd/len_ab`

translation by `(c.x, c.y)`

Comment: I made a small demo [here](https://jsbin.com/jorazalecu/edit?output). Something was wrong with the angle, so I compute it little bit differently.

Comment: Perhaps angle is reversed, try to negate it

Comment: this ans is cool. Note: for some code (not js), you might need angle/PI*180.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the same scale factor on both `x,y` axises you can: compute rotation angle:

```
ang = acos(dot(b-a,d-c)/|b-a|*|d-c|)
```

and scale:

```
scale = |d-c|/|b-a|
```

construct **2D** homogenuous **3x3** transform matrix with `origin = (0,0)` then convert `a` to `c'` by it and translate by:

```
translate = d-d'
```

**Another option is to solve this algebraically:**

```
M * p = p'
```

Where `M` is **3x3** homogenuous transfrom matrix

```
    | m0 m1 m2 |
M = | m3 m4 m5 |
    |  0  0  1 |
```

The `p=(x,y,1)` is original point `(a,b)` and `p'=(x,y,w)` is transformed point `(c,d)` so it forms this linear system:

```
m0.ax + m1.ay + m2 = cx
m3.ax + m4.ay + m5 = cy
m0.bx + m1.by + m2 = dx
m3.bx + m4.by + m5 = dy
m0.ux + m1.uy + m2 = vx
m3.ux + m4.uy + m5 = vy
ux = 0.5*(ax+bx)
uy = 0.5*(ay+by)
vx = 0.5*(cx+dx)
vy = 0.5*(cy+dy)
```

so just solve the `m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5` and you have the matrix ...

For more info see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)